# Why doesn't List.Add() trigger the Setter of property?

Tags: c#, list, properties, set, setter

I have a property of type `List<String>` named `SuggestionFirstName`. 
I Use MVVMlight, so I use a `Set()` in the setter

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> SuggestionFirstName
    {
        get { return _suggestionsFirstName; }
        set { Set(ref _suggestionsFirstName, value); }
    }
```

If i do

```
SuggestionLastName = new List<String>();
SuggestionLastName.Add("hello");
```

Why won't the second instruction trigger the `set{ }` method of the property?

Answer (score 4):

The SuggestionLastName is a property of some object, It is being set in this line:

```
SuggestionLastName = new List<String>();
```

see, it creates a **new list** and then it **sets** the property to remember that list.

Then, this line:

```
SuggestionLastName.Add("hello");
```

does the opposite: it **reads** the property to have a hold on that list, and then it adds the item directly to the **same list** it has just read from property. No "setting property" happens. Property is read and then **contents of the list** are changing. List has not changed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So is there any way I can trigger this myself ? Am I forced to use ObservableCollection ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout: Yes, if you want to "listen" on changes to the contents of the collection, you need to use a collection that emits notifications. ObservableCollection is one example of that. No, you are not forced to use it. You can use any other change-notifying collection, you can write your own (not that hard, really), or you can roll out your own change-detection based on something other than events. There are many possiblities, but in fact, ObservableCollection often is the easiest/quickest (not saying: fastest) to introduce into your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't trigger because you do not set anything to **property** `SuggestionLastName`.
What actually happens is you **get** value from property (which is list) and then add an item to it:

```
var list = SuggestionLastName; // getter triggered
lits.Add("hello");
```

See, nothing is being set :)